# Normal spaces that are not necessarily T1

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.

$X$ is normal provided any two disjoint closed subsets may be separated by disjoint open subsets.

$X$ is hereditarily normal provided every subspace is normal in the induced topology.

$X$ is PN1 (PN stands for 'perfectly normal') provided it is normal and every closed subset is a $G_\delta$.

$X$ is PN2 provided that for every closed subset $F$ there is a continuous function $f: \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = F$.

$X$ is PN3 provided that for any disjoint nonempty closed subsets $E$ and $F$ 
there is a continuous function $f: \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = E$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\}) =F$.

Note that I am not assuming that $X$ is T1.

Are the following correct?

Prop. 1. PN1 and PN2 are equivalent.

Prop. 2. PN2 implies PN3, but they are not equivalent.

Prop. 3. PN2 implies that $X$ is hereditarily normal.

Prop. 4. PN3 implies that $X$ is normal but does not imply that it is hereditarily normal.

Answer (score 1):

For PN3, I suppose you mean "disjoint closed sets" $E$ and $F$, or it makes no sense..

PN1 implies PN2 using the function series trick: if $E$ is closed, it is a $G_\delta$ so equals $\cap_n U_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $U_n$ open. Then using Urysohn functions $f_n$ into $[0,1]$ for $E$ ($0$ there) and $X \setminus U_n$ ($1$ there), we then define $f = \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}f_n$ as the required functions. AFAIK, Urysohn functions do not require $T_1$-ness to exist for normal spaces.

PN2 implies PN3 (for disjoint closed sets) because we take $f_1$ for $E$, $f_2$ for $F$ and then use $f = \frac{f_1^2}{f_1^2 + f_2^2}$ to work for both.

PN3 implies PN1 because we take $F$ to empty (if this is not allowed, it's going to be harder, maybe?).

So I say they are all equivalent.

It's clear that PN1 always implies hereditary normality, as open sets are $F_\sigma$, normality is hereditary for $F_\sigma$ sets and normality for all open subsets is equivalent
to being hereditarily normal. So all of them do.

Comment: Thanks, Henno. Stupid of me to omit 'disjoint'. I was also assuming nonempty in PN3 without saying it, and I've added that too. I think you are right about the equivalence of PN1, 2, & 3 without the nonempty assumption in PN3. What do you think as PN3 is stated now?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a set $X$ with at least two elements. Fix some $x_0\in X$. A set is closed if it is empty or it contains $x_0$.

There are no disjoint nonempty closed sets. So $X$ is PN3.

The singleton $\{x_0\}$ is closed. But it is not $G_\delta$ since the only open set contains $x_0$ is $X$, and this open set is not $\{x_0\}$. Hence, $X$ is not PN1.